# Simple if statement returning unexpected value

Tags: php, arrays

So I have this simple if statement with an input from an array:

```
var_dump($row);
if($row['Termijn'] == 0){
    $eenmalig = "selected";
}elseif($row['Termijn'] == 1){
    $maandelijks = "selected";
}elseif($row['Termijn'] == 2){
    $jaarlijks = "selected";
}
```

var_dump() returns:

```
(array) [12 elements]
0: (integer) 2 
ID: (integer) 2 
1: (string) "anderes"
Naam: (string) "anderes"
2: (string) "0.00"
Beschrijving: (string) "0.00"
3: (string) "0.00"
Prijs: (string) "0.00"
4: (string) ""
Prijsweergave: (string) ""
5: (integer) 2 
Termijn: (integer) 2
```

Seems simple right?

`Termijn` is set to 2 in the array and the if statements set jaarlijks to selected
well it doesn't matter if I use 0, 1 or 2 as inputs it always sets jaarlijks to selected

Comment: Please use `fetch_assoc()` as suggested earlier, that way you only get ONE version of each Column in the Row variable

Comment: Could this be because you dont clear the variables before each iteration of a loop?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Tried that already and it makes no difference on this issue

Comment: oh damn why didn't I see that earlier had to set the variables to 0 thnx @RiggsFolly pls add answer so I can approve

Comment: LOL, we have all been there :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is still the code you are playing with, you will need to initialise your variables each time round the loop otherwise their values will remain from the previosu iteration of the loop.

```
$module = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM modules");
$modulelist = $module->execute();
$results = $module->get_result();
while ( $row = $results->fetch_assoc() ){
    var_dump($row);

    // clear the variables before using them each time round the loop
    $eenmalig = $maandelijks = $jaarlijks = '';

    if($row['Termijn'] == 0) {
        $eenmalig = "selected";
    }elseif($row['Termijn'] == 1) {
        $maandelijks = "selected";
    }else {
        $jaarlijks = "selected";
    }

    // other code
}
```